# Javascript function with 2 parameter inside string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to insert multiple parameter inside javascript function inside string.

Example:

```
var a = '<a onclick="my_function(parameter1, parameter2)">Click</a>';
```

i tried  using

```
my_function(\''+parameter1+', '+parameter2+'\')
```

but not working.

Thanks all

Comment: @AnoopJoshi parameter1 is number, parameter2 is random string with -. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using jQuery create elements using it and also bind event using it. Here in example I have used `.data()` to store arbitrary value which can be fetched in the click handler

```
var a = $('<a>Click</a>')
        .data('parameter1', parameter1)
        .data('parameter2', parameter2)
        .on('click', function(){
            var parameter1 = $(this).data('parameter1');
            var parameter2 = $(this).data('parameter2');
            my_function(parameter1, parameter2)
        });
```

For immediate problem, you need to escape quotes properly

```
var a = '<a onclick="my_function(\''+ parameter1 + '\',\'' parameter2 + '\')">Click</a>';
```

As per comment `parameter1` is a number you don't need to wrap it.

```
var a = '<a onclick="my_function('+ parameter1 + ',\'' parameter2 + '\')">Click</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.innerHTML = "Click";
a.onclick = function(p1, p2) { ... your code here }
```